# MATLAB: Step through iterations of a vector

Tags: matlab, loops, permutation

all.

I have a 15 element array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15];.

I was wondering if there was a command such that it would step through iterations of the array without repeating itself. In other words, since there is a chance that randperm() will create the same matrix twice, I want to step through each permutation only once and perform a calculation.

I concede that there are factorial(15) permutations, but for my purposes, these two vectors (and similar) are identical and don't need to be counted twice:

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
[15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]

Thus, is there any way to step through this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Why is 1:15 identical to 15:-1:1? You mix iteration and permutation in your question.

Comment: For any element i in the test vector, it looks at a matrix 'connections' which dictates which nodes the element i is attached to. I'm trying to model a netlist, if that makes sense. Inasmuch, since the path from going forwards through a node is the same as going backwards through a node, 1:15 is identical to 15:-1:1 since the arrangement of the elements is identical relative to the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is perms.  randperm returns a single random permutation, you want all the permutations.

So use

```
my_permuations = perms([1:15]);
```

If forward-backward is the same as backward-foward then you can use the top half of the list only...

```
my_permutation_to_use = my_permutations(1:length(my_permutations)/2, :);
```

Comment: You need a lot of memory (or time) to run `perms([1:15])`

Answer (score 0):

You may compare all permutations, but this would require to store all past permutations. Instead a local decision is better. I recommend this simple rule:

- A permutation is valid, if the first element is smaller than the last element.
- A permutation is redundant, if the first element is larger than the last element.

For small sizes, this could simply be done with this code:

```
%generate all permutations
x=perms(1:10)
%select only the valid lines, remove all redundant lines 
x(x(:,1)<x(:,end),:)
```

Remains the problem, that generating x for `1:15` breaks all memory limits and would require about 100h.